# Casting to object

Tags: php, oop, object, casting

I've been reviewing some code that was made by another developer and I saw some lines that bother me. These are used all throughout the application.

Is there any particular reason why the developer would use type juggling/casting? I'm just curious as I find the code weird.

```
$object = (object) array();
$result = (object) json_decode($json);
```

Comment: You can turn an associative array to an object and back in PHP. It can sometime be useful, but in the two lines you posted it's pointless - the first line for obvious reasons, the second one because json_decode already returns an object by default.

Comment: @this.lau_ "the first line for obvious reasons"....can you explain why?

Comment: @dios231, because he creates an array, to then convert it to an object, while he could simply create an object right away with `new stdClass()`.

Comment: objects has one great property in php which is they are used as reference and array doesnt

Comment: Exactly! I was thinking there might be a special reason for it like micro optimization or some magic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(object) array()` is an obscure way to do `new stdClass()`.

`(object) json_decode($json)` is probably useless since `json_decode()` already maps objects to `stdClass` by default. This depends on the data being decoded.